# How to delay between to sets of keystrokes and mouse events in two different sheets

Tags: excel, winapi, vba

What is the way to delay two session of mouse events and key strokes in Excel? let say I perform two session in two different sheets:

sheet 1:

```
right click -> key stroke R -> write 100 chars -> press enter
```

after that:

switch to sheet 2:

```
right click -> key stroke R -> write 100 chars -> press enter
```

I used this delay but it seems that only the second sets of commands happens

```
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 10, Now)
```

Comment: do you mean you have a macro for operations in sheet1 , follow by the line `Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 10, Now)`, follow by another macro for operations in sheet2. But only macro2 is working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can try "onTime"? And I cannot reproduce your problem. Would you mind posting more codes?

```
Sub testing()
macroA
Application.OnTime DateAdd("s", 2, Now), "macroB"
End Sub

Sub macroA()
MsgBox "A"
End Sub
Public Sub macroB()
MsgBox "B"
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks man, that was brilliant. forgot there are timers in the world :)